# Check that the string is a number between 0 and 99

Tags: java

```
public class raceCar{
    private String driver;
    private String car;

    public raceCar(String driver, String car){
        this.driver = driver;
        this.car = car;
    }
}
```

I need to pass in two strings in the constructor, but the constructor needs to check that the string is a number between 0 and 99, If it is not, set it to "00".

Comment: [Convert int to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-to-convert-string-to-int-in-java), [basic if-then tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html).

Answer (score 3):

To test, use regex:

```
if (str.matches("[1-9]?\\d")) {
    // it's a number between 0 and 99
}
```

This works by using a [regular expression](http://regular-expressions.com/tutorial.html) to check the string. The parts of the expression are:

- `[1-9]?` a single character in the range 1 to 9, made optional by the `?`
- `\d` any digit

The regex could have been `\d\d`, but that would have allowed "00".

FYI, in java `String.matches()` only returns true if the *entire* String matches the pattern, so no need for ^ and $. This is unlike many other languages that return true for a partial match.

Comment: This is a great answer, but it may be harder for the opening poster to understand without an explanation of what's going on

Answer (score 2):

You could convert your string to an `int` using `Integer.parseInt()` and then use an if-statement to check if its both greater then -1 and less then 100.

Comment: This is something simple that a beginner to Java can understand.  Use try/catch with an if statement check under the try.

Comment: Thank you! This also works, and i've learned about it in class before

Answer (score 0):

```
public class raceCar
{
    private String driver;
    private String car;

    public raceCar(String driver, String car)
    {
        if (Integer.parseInt(driver) < 100 && Integer.parseInt(driver) >= 0)
            this.driver = driver;
        else
            this.driver = "00";

        if (Integer.parseInt(car) < 100 && Integer.parseInt(car) >= 0)
            this.car = car;
        else
            this.car = "00";
    }
```